# JavaScript to PHP data exchange via JSON not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, exchange-server

I created a simple contact us form that would capture the data and send to the server end via JSON and display it on the PHP page. I'm a beginner to this whole JSON thing. Please tell me where I've gone wrong.

JavaScript

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
var arr = {
      firstName : document.getElementById('fName').value,
      lastName  : document.getElementById('lName').value,
      email     : document.getElementById('email').value,
      comment   : document.getElementById('comment').value,
      rate      : document.getElementById('select').value
    };
  $.ajax({
    url: 'contact.php',
    type: "post",
    data: arr,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json"
    success: function(msg) {
    alert("msg");
    }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$example = $_POST['arr'];
echo $example;
?>
```

HTML

```
  <body>
  <h1> Contact Us </h1>
  We value your feedback. Send in your questions, suggestions, ideas to help us improve our service.

  <h2 align="Center"> Search us on Google Maps</h2>
<br> 
    <br>
  <div id="map-canvas" > </div>


    <form action="contact.php" name="form" method="post" >
   <div id= "result">
    <br>Name :<br>

    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"  required >

    &nbsp; &nbsp;
   <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName"  required >
    <br> <br>
    Email: <br>

    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required >

    <br> <br>
    Comment: <br>

    <textarea name= "comment" rows="8" cols="50"  autofocus></textarea>

     <br> <br>

    Rate our Website <select name="select" id="selected" autofocus>
    <option value = "1" name= "rate"> 1 </option>
    <option value = "2" name= "rate"> 2 </option>
    <option value = "3" name= "rate"> 3 </option>
    <option value = "4" name= "rate"> 4 </option>
    <option value = "5" name= "rate"> 5 </option>

    </select>

     <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: Try using the code as written as change the echo to `echo $_POST['name'];`. I do not see where you are sending `arr` via AJAX. The only data you are sending to the script is single variable `name`. THe data to be posted is what the `data` attribute of the AJAX call should be.

Comment: It looks like you are simply sending data: ({name: 145}), as the data so the php call to $_POST['arr'] will not find anything as it never gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call, your data that you are sending over is just "name : 145", so the only thing in your post will be $_POST['name']. The arr value is never passed to you AJAX function, so it will not pass 'arr' over.

What you are looking for would be this if you want the PHP side to remain the same:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr = {arr: {
    firstName : document.getElementById('fName').value,
    lastName  : document.getElementById('lName').value,
    email     : document.getElementById('email').value,
    comment   : document.getElementById('comment').value,
    rate      : document.getElementById('select').value
}};
$.ajax({
    url: 'contact.php',
    type: "post",
    data: arr,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json"
    success: function(msg) {
    alert("msg");
}
});
});
```

When you use JSON, what gets sent through the post request looks like this:

For a JSON array that is formatted in this way:

```
var json = { 'name' : 'leneya', 'id' : '74'}
```

Your PHP $_POST array will look like:

```
$_POST['name'] => 'leneya'
$_POST['id'] => '74'
```

If I were you, I'd probably format my JSON as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr = {
  firstName : document.getElementById('fName').value,
  lastName  : document.getElementById('lName').value,
  email     : document.getElementById('email').value,
  comment   : document.getElementById('comment').value,
  rate      : document.getElementById('select').value
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'contact.php',
    type: "post",
    data: arr,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json"
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("msg");
    }
});
});
```

Notice how I pass the arr variable into data, because that is how you send JSON through the AJAX request.

Then on the PHP side, you can now use $_POST['firstName'] to get just the first name, $_POST['email'] to get the email, and so on.

**Edit**

Since your are running $.ajax on $(document).ready(), jQuery is running the ajax function as soon as the page loads. What I'm assuming you want is to submit the form once the user clicks the "Submit" button. To do this, you need to adjust your javascript:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
        //this line binds the ajax functionality to the click of the submit button
        $('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e){
            //this prevents the form from submitting itself to php.
            e.preventDefault();

            var arr = {
                firstName : document.getElementById('fName').value,
                lastName  : document.getElementById('lName').value,
                email     : document.getElementById('email').value,
                comment   : document.getElementById('comment').value,
                rate      : document.getElementById('select').value
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'contact.php',
                type: "post",
                data: arr,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json"
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("msg");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

On the PHP side, you will now be able to access your keys according to the JSON array.

```
$_POST['firstName'], 
$_POST['lastName'], 
$_POST['email'] ...
```

Again, the keys in your post array should match up with the keys in your JSON array. If they don't, then your AJAX is still not working. In addition, you will be able to tell if the AJAX is working, because you should get an "alert" from javascript that displays whatever message you have echoed from PHP.

Comment: I've changed everything to what you said above but i'm getting an error like this. 
Notice: Undefined index: firstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.php on line 11

Comment: can you var_dump($_POST) and let me know what it says?

Comment: array(6) { ["fName"]=> string(5) "akila" ["lName"]=> string(13) "Hettiarachchi" ["email"]=> string(15) "akila@gmail.com" ["comment"]=> string(3) "cas" ["select"]=> string(1) "1" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }

Comment: Instead of accessing firstName using $_POST['firstName'] access it using $_POST['fName']; on the php side

Comment: I'm assuming that your JSON looks like

   var arr = { 'fName' : 'akila' , 'lName' : 'hettiarachchi' .... }

You must access your $_POST array keys with the same keys from your JSON array. In this case, 'fName' is your JSON key, so your $_POST key will also be 'fName'

Comment: This is the result for var_dump($_POST['fName']);  ----  >
string(5) "akila"

Comment: Yes. But how do i know that it is being sent via JSON? it might be grabbing the value from 'fName' textbox itself.

Comment: Even without the AJAX code, I still get this result-> string(5) "akila"

Comment: Does the page reload? If so it is not using AJAX. One way to test it would be to change your JSON keys to something ridiculous like 'yrnfs' : 'akilia'. If $_POST['yrnfs'] does not exist, then your ajax is not being called.

Comment: Just as a note, the way you are calling the AJAX in your function above is submitting your AJAX request WHEN THE PAGE LOADS not when you click the submit button

Comment: If you want to submit the ajax request WHEN YOU HIT THE SUBMIT BUTTON, I can edit the answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: I can, but you need to update your question with your HTML form that is providing the data. Then I will be able to update the answer.

Comment: I did change the code. and I am getting an echo but I'm still not sure that JSON is working properly. The alert is not working.

Comment: Plus, how can u put the data into an encrypted JSON object and decrypt and extract the data in the PHP? Cause that what I eventually should do.

Comment: At this point, I would say that to make sure the JSON / AJAX call are working, you should put alerts in at each point in the javascript to see where it is failing. So put one inside of document.ready, one right above e.preventDefault() to see if it gets past there. This is debugging of the script. In addition, I would recommend using chrome's developer tools or mozilla's firebug to see if there are any javascript errors popping up, and resolve those errors. Outside of writing the whole thing myself, I'm not sure there's much more help I can give from my side.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
data: ({name: 145}),
```

with

```
data: {arr: arr},
```